# Need help hacking a solution to a bmw e61 (2007 530xi wagon) rear air suspension failure

Tags: suspension, bmw

I brought the car to a shop to have the front struts replaced because I didn't have time to do it, and when I get it back, the rear suspension is completely deflated.

I take a look and (it had rained) there's water everywhere. The previous owner had moved all the computer modules out of the spare tire well to the driver's side storage pocket area and guess what... water gets in there too. The black lcpa module has water pouring out of it. I don't care about that one, apparently it's for the cover slide control. Whatever.

I unplug what google tells me by part number is the controller for the suspension and... one of the pins is broken off from rot. there's dirt in there too, there has been water in there before. I take the module apart, and it's clean and shiny only the one pin is in bad shape. So I solder the wire from the plug on the harness to the correct pin on the back of module. Doesn't help, still nothing.

I go to look at the compressor, I eventually wrench off the power plug to the compressor to find that one of the terminals melted the plastic and fused the two sides of the connector together, which is why I had such a hard time getting it apart.

I still don't know what's actually broken, but realizing the dealer would want to replace everything for an exorbitant fee, I start looking for other options. First I look for a coil spring conversion kit. no such thing for this car. So I'm stuck getting the air suspension working somehow, then I come across this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTlYoqoyYGc

The impression I get is that you can pump air into the system through the little tube that comes out of the output of the compressor and to release air from the system, you apply voltage to that electric valve and that will let air out. But it gets confusing at the end, not sure if I have to open that valve to let air in too...

So I hook my air pump up to the little tube and it says it's pushing 90-100psi. I have no idea what the pressure is supposed to be, but the suspension isn't lifting.

Anybody have any suggestions? I just need this thing not to be sagging on the ground? No idea how to figure out what's wrong, and I'd be happy to manually add air as needed, but I can't even seem to do that.

Help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out reading the comments on youtube proved helpful.
The valve you run 12v to isn't just for letting air out of the system, it's also for letting air in.
So once I ran power to the valve, I was able to pump more air in. Got it up to pressure (about 90psi) and the car rides normal again.
Not actually fixed, but a workable solution.